# Rescatar valor enviado en javascript y c# mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, mvc

Mi consulta es la siguiente tengo dos botones en mi formulario
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ambos cumplen la misma funcion que es editar el registro lo unico que cambia es el estado cuando se pincha cada uno de los botones Actualizar Rendicion debe ir con codigo 3 y Actualizar enviar codigo 6

```html
        <div class="col-md-4 col-12">
             
            <button type="submit" class="btn btnNegro"   id="btnActualizar" ><i class="fas fa-save"  aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp; Actualizar rendición</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btnVerde"   id="btnEnviar"><i class="fas fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp; Actualizar y Enviar rendición</button>

              
        </div>
```

Asi genero la funcion mi problema es como pasarle dichos estado al ClaseBO

Comment: Con un form y un controller

Comment: ya teno listo js de la siguiente forma function funcionCodigoEstado(valor) {

    if (valor == 1)
    {
        $("#valorBotonera").val("6");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#valorBotonera").val("3");
    }
} aqui se me genera el problema como tomar dicho valor en view para despues trabajar con ese valor al momento de editar el registro